# next-auth | invalid_client (The OAuth client was not found.)

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm using GoogleProvider (nextAuth library). I got this error :

---

[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error invalid_client (The OAuth client was not found.) {
error: OPError: invalid_client (The OAuth client was not found.)
at processResponse (C:\Users\cmos\Desktop\moslemi-phone\node_modules\openid-client\lib\helpers\process_response.js:38:13)
at Client.grant (C:\Users\cmos\Desktop\moslemi-phone\node_modules\openid-client\lib\client.js:1354:22)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Client.callback (C:\Users\cmos\Desktop\moslemi-phone\node_modules\openid-client\lib\client.js:493:24)
at async oAuthCallback (C:\Users\cmos\Desktop\moslemi-phone\node_modules\next-auth\core\lib\oauth\callback.js:109:16)
at async Object.callback (C:\Users\cmos\Desktop\moslemi-phone\node_modules\next-auth\core\routes\callback.js:52:11)
at async AuthHandler (C:\Users\cmos\Desktop\moslemi-phone\node_modules\next-auth\core\index.js:208:28)
at async NextAuthApiHandler (C:\Users\cmos\Desktop\moslemi-phone\node_modules\next-auth\next\index.js:22:19)
at async NextAuth._args$ (C:\Users\cmos\Desktop\moslemi-phone\node_modules\next-auth\next\index.js:108:14) {
name: 'OAuthCallbackError',
code: undefined
},
**message: 'invalid_client (The OAuth client was not found.)'**
}

---

I have searched for find the solution and I read just some tips like :

see if you add space at .env file

don't write quotation at .env file

but I know my id client is valid , what should I do? thanks for your response